# Is there always one instance of Billing Service on Android?

Tags: android, service

In the Google's In App Billing example(Dungeons) there is a Service instance created in main Activity onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mHandler = new Handler();
    mDungeonsPurchaseObserver = new DungeonsPurchaseObserver(mHandler);
    mBillingService = new BillingService();
    mBillingService.setContext(this);
    ....
 }
```

and in the receiver the service is started by the context.startService.

```
private void notify(Context context, String notifyId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Consts.ACTION_GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION);
    intent.setClass(context, BillingService.class);
    intent.putExtra(Consts.NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyId);
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

Will notify use somehow the some instance created in onCreate or it will create another instance of this class running as an actual service?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "allways one instance"? Is that important?
As far as I know, when receiver get it, It starts the service and check the user has actually bought it (i.e. get purchase info). After the service has completed, it send a broadcast message to you, so that you can act accordingly. I don't think that it runs always in the background.

Comment: In my understanding service, that is started, will run until terminated. In the Dungones example it is done: 

public void unbind() {
    try {
        unbindService(this);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
}

But this is called only on instance created in onCreate method, so if there were two instances second will leak?

Comment: Why do you want to know the inner functions of the library. You can simply use it. I am using this library: http://www.robotmedia.net/2011/06/android-billing-library-in-app-billing-made-simple/ It is simpler then the one Google has provided.

Comment: However, I think the service do the network connection and update stuff and terminate when it finishes. If it is started twice, It will run twice and notify your app twice. I think it is not a big problem. No leak is possible.